# why we integrate Qt with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I think Qt IDE(Qt creater) is itself enough to develop better to best project than any other language tools, then why we go for visual studio integration. is there have any advantage in doing so, kindly give a light upon this.

thak's in advace

Comment: Retagged with subjective, since this question is.

Answer (score 3):

The VS plugin was around before Qt Creator, so was the Eclipse plugin.  Choice is one of the driving ideas behind open source software, so I don't see why both can't be developed.

If you like Qt Creator and are happy with it, then keep using it.  The "advantage" to the VS plugin is that it's available if you're already comfortable with using VS and don't want to learn a new IDE, or maybe your company requires that you use VS.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine this question will be closed as subjective and argumentative, but basically it comes down to the popularity of Visual Studio for developing Windows applications, and the relative newness of Qt Creator. Not really much else to it. I still use Visual Studio for my Qt apps, mainly from inertia.

Comment: Does Qt Creator have an integrated debugger? I've only tested it very briefly and don't recall. Integrated debugger is important to many people who use VS

Comment: Yes. Qt-Creator includes integration with a debugger. (gdb on linux and cdb on windows)

Answer (score 1):

I think Qt Creator is a beautiful tool... It's easy to use, it's a nice IDE... It also have the advantage of helping a lot people for multi-plateforme development... But at the moment, Visual Studio is much more powerful and it's faster (Sam: yes, there is a debugger, but gosh, it's so slow...)...

Nevertheless, I think Nokia is doing a serious and cool job with Qt Creator, and I regularly test new versions of QtCreator... I think Qt Creator is just a little to young to fight against Visual Studio...

Give Qt Creator a few months and I'm pretty sure lot of people will consider passing to it instead of VS...